# Use if statement in createRoutesFromElements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom@6.17.0`, with `if` inside `createRoutesFromElements` like this:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements
} from 'react-router-dom'
import EsportsRouter from './esport'
import SportsbookRouter from './sportsbook'

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      {isEsports ? EsportsRouter : SportsbookRouter}
    </>,
  ),
)

export default router
```

I can only access the route `'/'` and got an error "route not found" when I navigate to `'/games'`, `'/game/tournament'` and so on.
How can I use `if` statement to get router on demand?

Comment: What are these different routers and what is `isEsports`? Where and how are you navigating through the app? Please [edit] to clarify the problem, reproduction steps, and to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant routing and navigation code you are working with.

Comment: Does [How to create a protected route with React-Router-DOM](/a/66289280/8690857) help answer your question?